# Logical vector to see wether an element of a df is contained within a df inside a List

Tags: r, list, logical-operators

I tried:

```
mdf$CLAVE.EMISORA %in% BMV[[9]]$`CLAVE EMISORA`
```

But it only returns:

```
logical(0)
```

For some reason the reveres seems to work:

```
BMV[[9]]$`CLAVE EMISORA` %in% mdf$CLAVE.EMISORA 


[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[20] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[39] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[58] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[77] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

My data (mdf): I have it but I don't know how to embed

My list (BMV): .... I don't know how to copy a list to clipboard sorry...

Comment: Hi! Just like you have wrapped the output of ```BMV[[9]]$ `CLAVE EMISORA` %in% mdf$CLAVE.EMISORA``` in a code block, could you maybe show the output of `head(mdf)` or `str(mdf)`? And maybe also do the same but for `BMV[[9]]`? It would be of help in understanding the problem ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logical(0)` is a vector of base type logical with 0 length.

You're getting this because your trying to check if any element in a vector of length 0 is present in BMV[[9]]$'CLAVE EMISORA'

if you run

```
length(mdf$CLAVE.EMISORA)
```

You'll get 0 as output

Reverse works because you're checking if any element from a vector of a non-zero length is present in a vector of 0 length.

Comment: Yeah actually mdf$`CLAVE EMISORA` %in% BMV[[1]][[1]] worked, it doesn't matter how many times I always find typos.